# Yii2 bootstrap 3 less issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

1. Yii2 basic application new instance.
2. Open start page page.
3. Content div.container has styles from grid.less. grid.less:

> ```
> .container {
>   .container-fixed();
>
>   @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
>     width: @container-sm;
>   }
>   @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
>     width: @container-md;
>   }
>   @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
>     width: @container-lg;
>   }
> }
> ```

4. On page only bootstrap.css and js.

How to unlink less files from bootstrap?

screen shot:

[image]

Comment: unclear what you are asking, if you are using a fresh install there isnt any issue currently with the css, you might need to provide more info.

Comment: I could not understand how yii2 publish bootstrap asset by default and how less files (for example grid.less) was included to page. As I see in page source no any link to less files. Searching in yii2 project files for '.less' string shows nothing to me. Also disabling 'debug' module has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

By default [yii2-bootstrap](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap) does not do anything with `.less` files - it uses [compiled CSS distributed in `bower-asset/bootstrap` package](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css). If you want to adjust some CSS using `.less`, you need to create your own assets bundle with necessary modifications, configure compiling assets and override paths used by bootstrap assets:

> ```
> return [
>     'components' => [
>         'assetManager' => [
>             // setup asset converter for *.less files :
>             'converter' => [
>                 'class' => 'yii\web\AssetConverter',
>                 'commands' => [
>                     'less' => ['css', 'lessc {from} {to} --no-color'],
>                 ],
>             ],
>             // override bundles to use local project files :
>             'bundles' => [
>                 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
>                     'sourcePath' => '@app/assets/source/bootstrap',
>                     'css' => [
>                         'css/bootstrap.less'
>                     ],
>                 ],
>                 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
>                     'sourcePath' => '@app/assets/source/bootstrap',
>                 ],
>                 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapThemeAsset' => [
>                     'sourcePath' => '@app/assets/source/bootstrap',
>                 ],
>             ],
>         ],
>         // ...
>     ],
>     // ...
> ];
> ```
>
> <sub>https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/guide/2.0/en/assets-setup#compiling-from-the-less-files</sub>

---

Regarding these `.less` files visible in browser inspector - these comes from `.map` files distributed with compiled assets: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v3.4.0/dist/css. These are only additional metadata loaded by browser if you open developer tools, they're not actually used as source for styles.